# Ubuntu 20.04 Install a Java web app that requires 32 bit libraries

Tags: icedtea

I have a JNLP file that when it starts the install errors for not having:
RROR: package libXtst.i686 is not installed
ERROR: package libgcc.i686 is not installed
ERROR: package libXrender.i686 is not installed

The base packages are installed ex. libxtst6 but I can't find a .686 version of the library.  I do have multarch installed but that doesn't seem to help.  How  do I work around the above errors?

Comment: Are you sure the app runs on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Yes, I had it working then Ubuntu did a update and I haven't been able to get it back since.  I've done the basics of uninstalling everything and re-installing but getting that same error each time.